# How can I build an arara rule for running perl scripts

Tags: arara, perl

I want to write an arara rule for perl scripts, especially for [fancy-preview](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/#installation).
(Another test-script: [latexcount](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/latexcount.html).)

---

**Edit:**

1. In the Command-Line
   `perl fancy-preview jobname.tex` works!
2. I have installed `ActiveState Perl`

---

This does not work

```
!config
# perl rule for arara
# version: 0.1
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: perl
name: Perl
command: <arara> @{program} @{script} @{getBasename(file)} @{options}
arguments:
- identifier: program
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.program}
  default: cmd /c  perl
- identifier: script
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.script}
  default: fancy-preview
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
  default: --fancy_options="previewall,nosoap"
```

Error Comment:

```
Running Perl... 

Can't locate Config/IniFiles.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/texlive/2013/tlpkg/tlperl/lib c:/texlive/2013/tlpkg/tlperl/lib .) at fancy-preview line 227.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at fancy-preview line 227.
FAILURE
C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:650: command failed with exit code 1:
java.exe -jar c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.jar interaktiv2.tex --verbose --log
```

What can I do?

---

**EDIT1:**

The "rule" above  is a first draft-version.

For the result, I thought about an `inputpath: 'C:/MyPerlScripts/...'` or so on - so I have not to build a coupled motion for my perl-scripts and could store them under a central place. But for this and others, the rule has to run `;)` ...

---

**EDIT2:**

**If I change**

```
 - identifier: program
      flag: <arara> @{parameters.program}
      default: cmd /c start perl
```

**there is no error-messgage but the perls scripts were not runned (ok, this only for Windows, but it does not work) - I do not understand! :(**

---

**Edit3:**

Same effect as Edit2:

```
 - identifier: program
      flag: <arara> @{parameters.program}
      default: cmd /c start C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe
```

Same without 'start':

```
Running Perl... 

Perl lib version (5.16.2) doesn't match executable 'fancy-preview.pl' version (v5.16.3) at C:/texlive/2013/tlpkg/tlperl/lib/Config.pm line 60.
Compilation failed in require at C:/texlive/2013/tlpkg/tlperl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 22 ....
```

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

## A litte message of partially success

I think the problem is partly the script `fancy-preview` and partly `arara`.

Because: If I use the script [latexcount](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/latexcount.html) with "`perl.yaml`" as given above on the following document

```
% arara: perl: { script: latexcount.pl }

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Count these words!
\end{document}
```

I get

```
Can't open --fancy_options=previewall,nosoap: No such file or directory at latexcount.pl line 72, <> line 8.

3 words in the main text
 in the footnotes
3 total

Status: SUCCESS
```

This is correct *in each line*!

**I think (at `fancy-preview` etc.) `arara` stops, if there is a warning or something else. In that case, I do not know, what to do - this could be `arara`-interna or not? The authors-team are the last hope :()**

Comment: Can you run the `perl` command you are aiming for from the command line without `arara` being involved? Because the error looks like `perl` can't find one of the modules required by `fancy-preview` and that wouldn't be a problem with the `arara` rule.

Comment: The Perl in TeX Live is a rather restricted version only with modules, needed by the TeX Live Manager. Other Perl scripts might need a full Perl with additional modules.

Comment: Sry, I forgot some informations (see edit). Yes, the classical way works (with "full perl")

Comment: Nobody an idea? :()

Comment: So the full version of `perl` you have installed is not part of TeX Live, correct? In that case, I'd suggest specifying the full path to the correct `perl`. I suspect - though I'm not sure - that when `arara` runs it is picking up a different `perl` from the version you are getting at the command line. Notice that `@INC` only includes directories for what I assume is the TeX Live `perl`. [I do not use Windows so cannot be sure of this. But that's certainly what it looks like.] Also did you install the `perl` library mentioned in the link you posted (`Config::IniFiles`)?

Comment: Yes, for fancy-preview, you have to install 'config-inifiles'. I added another perl-script for testing.

Comment: Can you not do something like `C:\Some\Windows\Path\perl.exe` or whatever rather than using `start`? Note this is a real know-nothing question. But is there an equivalent of `/usr/bin/perl` where you just specify the direct path to the executable?

Comment: Regrettably not (I added 'Edit3'). In Linux this works, yes?

Comment: It shouldn't be using e.g.`C:/texlive/2013/tlpkg/tlperl/lib/DynaLoader.pm` because that library will match TL's `perl` ***not*** your system `perl`. That's what the mismatch error is complaining about. It is using the wrong `@INC`. I don't know what the values should be on Windows but you need to put the relevant directories probably before the TL ones in the equivalent of `PATH`. On my system, for example, I'd need to put `/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl` before `/usr/local/texlive/bin` if I had `perl` binaries in TL which I wished to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think, thats it:

**·** identifier `program` : please choose your own perl version here as default. In the most cases, artless "`perl`" is written here

**·** identifier `inputfile`:  choose

```
% arara: perl: {script: xyz.pl , inputfile: '' }
```

for an empty value, for example in these cases, when the perl-script is not executed on a tex-file.

**·**  boolean identifier `onlylog` gives the perl-log as `perl_log.txt`

```
% arara: perl: {script: xyz.pl , onlylog: yes }
```

Check (for Linux) if you need `^> perl_log.txt`     instead  of `> perl_log.txt`

**·** identifier `inputpath` choose the path to the folder, which contains your perl-scripts ;)

**·** identifiers `compile` and `options`:

Example:

```
% HELP:
% Help-Info "fancy-preview":
% #arara: perl: { script: fancy-preview.pl , options: -h }

% Help-Info "perl":
% #arara: perl: { script: latexcount.pl , compile: -h }
```

---

`perl.yaml`

```
!config
# perl rule for arara
# version: 0.2a
# requires arara 3.0+, PERL
#
#  ### 
#  Please check defaults at 'program', 'inputpath' (and 'onlylog') !
#  ###
#
identifier: perl
name: Perl
command: <arara> @{program} @{compile} @{inputpath}@{script} @{inputfile} @{options} @{onlylog}
arguments:
- identifier: program
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.program}
  default: 'cmd /c c:\texlive\2013\tlpkg\tlperl\bin\perl.exe'  
#  default: <arara> @{ isWindows("cmd /c  perl", "perl") }
#  default: 'cmd /c  c:\Perl\bin\perl.exe'
- identifier: compile
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.compile}
- identifier: inputpath
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.inputpath}
  default: 'C:\Users\ccc\PerlScripts\'
- identifier: script
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.script}
- identifier: inputfile
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.inputfile}
  default: <arara> @{getBasename(file)}.tex
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
- identifier: onlylog
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( parameters.onlylog , "> perl_log.txt"  ) }
```

I tested with success:  [latexcount.pl](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/latexcount.html) and [fancy-preview.pl](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/#installation) (Warning: at `fancy-preview.pl`  you have to do some   preliminary work - pm-modules, acrotex-packages).

**Example**

```
% arara: perl: { script: latexcount.pl  }

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Count these words, immediately! 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So that uses Tex Live's `perl` after all? In that case, it won't work as a general solution for running scripts, right? Even though it works for this particular case?

Comment: I'll try to write an answer today. `:)`

Comment: Hi, you two. In  >>my<< case, I decided, to use TL-perl. But there is no commitment to this (as I said, choose your own perl as default at the 'program'-identifier). My solution was: I added thoose perl-pm-modules on the path, where the compiler missed them - so it works (especially at `fancy-preview`) ;)

Comment: @cfr: Could you say me please: Does perl.yaml as shown above work on your Linux-system? (By setting your own defaults.)

Comment: @cis Well that won't tell you much. I don't have a TeX Live version of `perl` to override. If you are mixing modules you installed with your system `perl` with the TL executable then you will run into trouble if one or other gets updated out-of-sync. That is, the fact that it works now is partly luck and I don't think this solution should be regarded as robust.

Comment: @cis This solution/answer is not working for arara 4.0 (and maybe current 5.0). Could you please help me or provide guidance how to update rule you created here? Or should I post separate question?

Comment: @TomášKruliš I was some kind of "arara 3.0 expert". But later... :()  Better you ask PauloCereda, the author, he is often in the chat....